# Custom confirm modal is not working for browser back with history.block method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router';

const MyComponent = ({
    when
}) => {
    const history = useHistory();

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
    const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState('');

    useEffect(
        () => {
            let isChangesPresent = when instanceof Function ? when() : when;
            if (isChangesPresent) {
                history.block(prompt => {
                    setCurrentPath(prompt.pathname);
                    setShowModal(true);
                    return false;
                });
            } else {
                history.block(() => {});
            }

            return () => {
                history.block(() => {});
            };
        },
        [history, when]
    );
    return showModal ? (
        <MyCustomModal/>
    ) : null;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

We want to display a custom modal whenever user tries to navigate away from the page.

The above code is working for all within page navigations but I could see when user clicks on browser back the modal is coming up and the page is getting reloaded parallelly which is why we are not able to see the custom confirm modal.

Comment: This doesn't quite seem like enough code to be considered a [mcve]. What is `history` and `when`? Can you [edit] to include a more complete minimal and reproducible code example, and to include better details to clarify the issue and reproduction steps?